Chinese cartoon with beetles like rhino and stag beetles head with body like car with wheels they battle each other
I don’t remember much but it was like a bakugon type of show with a lot of car either beetles head and they each have owner/tamer using them for battle

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-animated (3D)?

Armoured Beetles? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=H-3EXQtuj6k

Which Bakugan show? There have been several, some hand-drawn and some full CGI

@Valorum oh hey, I watched that! When reading the question, I thought “oh this sounds familiar”, and then I saw someone (you) had put it in a comment :laugh_emoji_here:
